# How to share different tabs in the same Google Sheet with different people/groups

Tags: google-sheets, sharing, permissions

I usually create Google Sheets that have several tabs. Usually the audience of each tab should be completely separate.

However it makes sense to keep these tabs in the *same* sheet since I like to have a final *summary* tab that aggregates data from all these sheets.

Is there a way to share the *same* Google Sheet but by giving different viewing rights to each tab?

I thought that restricting a sheet would work. Turns out that this is only about who can *edit* a sheet. Here are the instructions:

click on tab > protect sheet > set who can see the sheet

[image: sheet menu]

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this problem is simply creating different spreadsheets, and then having a "summary" spreadsheet that references those other spreadsheets using the method described [in this Google forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/MqN9hHkwblA).